# Read in the first column of a CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV (mylist.csv) with 2 columns that look similar to this:

```
jfj840398jgg     item-2f
hd883hb2kjsd     item-9k
jie9hgtrbu43     item-12
fjoi439jgnso     item-3i
```

I need to read the first column into a variable so I just get:

```
jfj840398jgg
hd883hb2kjsd
jie9hgtrbu43
fjoi439jgnso
```

I tried the following, but it is only giving me the first letter of each column:

```
import csv
list2 = []
with open("mylist.csv") as f:
    for row in f:
        list2.append(row[0])
```

So the results of the above code are giving me `list2` as:

```
['j', 'h', 'j', 'f']
```

Comment: You need `split()` lines and then get the first element.

Comment: there is no need to import `csv` if you are not using it and you are not. you are just reading the file as if it was a `txt` let's say. In that case, do it like @vishes_shell says.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should `split` the row and then append the first item

```
list2 = []
with open("mylist.csv") as f:
    for row in f:
        list2.append(row.split()[0])
```

You could also use a *list comprehension* which are pretty standard for creating lists:

```
with open("mylist.csv") as f:
    list2 = [row.split()[0] for row in f]
```

Comment: that works only if the `csv` uses whitespace for the delimiters

Comment: @Ev.Kounis his csv is using whitespace for the delimiters

Comment: And you can further make that `row.split(None, 1)[0]` to avoid splitting all columns...

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) here:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(mylist.csv)
```

Then, getting the first column is as easy as:

```
matrix2 = df[df.columns[0]].as_matrix()
list2 = matrix2.tolist()
```

This will return only the first column in `list`. You might want to consider leaving the data in `numpy`, if you're conducting further data operation on the result you get.

Comment: This code doesn't work as expected, the line
matrix2 = df[df.columns[0]].as_matrix()
is generating an error. I had to remove the "is_matrix()" call and that fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `csv` module:

```
import csv

with open("processes_infos.csv", "r", newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0], row[1])
```

You can change the delimiter `","` into `"     "`.

Comment: this prints the all rows from that file. how can I get specific column data from any row of CSV?

Answer (score 4):

you import `csv`, but then never use it to actually read the CSV.  Then you open `mylist.csv` as a normal file, so when you declare:

```
 for row in f:
    list2.append(row[0])
```

What you're actually telling Python to do is "iterate through the lines, and append the first element of the lines (which would be the first letter) to `list2`".  What you need to do, if you want to use the CSV module, is:

```
import csv
with open('mylist.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='     ')
    for row in csv_reader:
        list2.append(row[0])
```

Answer (score -3):

The simplest answer

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(mylist.csv)
matrix2 = df[df.columns[0]].to_numpy()
list1 = matrix2.tolist()
print(list1)
```